# SonarQube Eclipse plugin analysis fails because plugin points to wrong .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, sonarqube, analysis

- Eclipse: "Luna" Release 2 (4.4.2) [20150219-0600]
- Sonar: 5.1 (under Java 1.7.0_76)
- Sonar Eclipse plugin: 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE

*(Major edits because behavior is now more clear)*

We do Sonar analysis as part of our nightly CI builds on our integration branch, and we want to use the Sonar Eclipse plugin so that we can work on our code and "see" the fixes acknowledged by Eclipse as we make them, as part of our pre-commit activity.

**Here's the problem:** In the "SonarQube Issues" view, the issues shown when the cursor is in a given .java file are just the ones from the last nightly CI build.  When I select **{Project} > SonarQube > Analyze**, I get the following error:

```
Error during execution of Sonar Error status [command:
 C:\eRA_Desktop\Java\1.8.0_31\jre\bin\java.exe
    -cp C:\Users\eryq\AppData\Local\Temp\1\sonar-runner-impl2312805194256028820.jar
     org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain
     C:\Users\eryq\AppData\Local\Temp\1\sonar-project8027650976823258460.properties
]: 1
```

If I run this from the command line, I get:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain

Which gives me the big clue to look in the C:\Users\eryq\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ directory, whereupon I find that *neither* the .jar file nor the .properties files are there.

There *is* a .jar file, but instead of the name being "sonar-runner-impl2312805194256028820.jar", it's "sonar-runner-batch2842147209529801286.jar".

We do have a slightly-odd setup with Eclipse links, so I set the **sonar.sources** directory in the project's Preview Analysis Properties to point to the physical path of the top-level source directory, but other than that it's a fairly straightforward setup.

Any idea what could be causing this?  Thanks!

Eryq